# ¿Cómo resolver la advertencia: "Passing argument from incompatible pointer type"?

Tags: c

Estuve haciendo programación en C y no logro hacer funcionar este programa que no marca errores sino que solo menciona advertencias. El código y las advertencias están copiadas y pegadas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int estadia (int horai, int mini, int horae, int mine){

int mintransc;

if (horae<horai){
    horae=horae+24;
    }
mintransc=(horae*60+mine)-(horai*60+mini);
return (mintransc);
}

void sub_carga (FILE *a, int*minxcochera[180][2]){
int cochera,horain,minin,horaeg,mineg,i,j;
char patente[7],turno,*tur;

for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    for (j=0;j<180;j++){
        *minxcochera[j][i]=0;
    }
}
fscanf(a,"%d %d %d %d %d %s %c",&cochera,&horain,&minin,&horaeg,&mineg,patente,&turno);
*tur=turno;
if (tur=="M"){
    tur="1";
}
else {
    tur="2";
}
while (!feof(a)){
    *minxcochera[cochera][turno]=*minxcochera[cochera][turno]+estadia(horain,minin,horaeg,mineg);
}
}

void sub_tiempoxcochera (int minxcochera[180][2]){
int mintotalxcochera[180],i;
for (i=0;i<180;i++){
    mintotalxcochera[i]=minxcochera[i][1]+minxcochera[i][2];
    printf("El tiempo total ocupado en la cochera %d es de %d minutos",i,mintotalxcochera[i]);
}
}

void sub_tiempoxturno(int minxcochera[180][2],int *totalxturno[2]){
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    for (j=0;j<180;j++){
        *totalxturno[i]=*totalxturno[i]+minxcochera[j][i];
    }
}
}

int main(){
int opc,minxcoch[180][2],i,j,totalxturno[2],cochera,horaing,mining,horaegr,minegr,control;
char turno,pat[7],patente[7],turn;
FILE *a;
a=fopen("ingresos.txt","r");
if (a == NULL) {
    printf( "No se puede abrir el fichero.\n" );
}
else{
    printf("Bienvenido al programa\nElija una opcion:\n1-Carga\n2-Tiempo por cochera\n3-Tiempo por turno\n4-Buscar por patente\n5-Fin del programa\n");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    switch (opc){
        case 1:
            sub_carga(a,&minxcoch[180][2]);
            for (i=0;i<180;i++){
                for (j=0;j<2;j++){
                 if (j==0){
                    turno="M";
                 }
                 else{
                    turno="T";
                 }
                 printf("La cochera numero %d estuvo ocupada en el turno %c por %d minutos",i,turno,minxcoch);
                 }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            sub_carga(a,&minxcoch[180][2]);
            sub_tiempoxcochera(minxcoch[180][2]);
            break;
        case 3:
            sub_carga(a,&minxcoch[180][2]);
            sub_tiempoxturno(minxcoch,&totalxturno[2]);
            for (i=0;i<2;i++){
                if (i==1){
                    turno="M";
                }
                else{
                    turno="T";
                }
                printf("El tiempo total por el turno %c fue de %d minutos",turno,totalxturno);
             }
             break;
        case 4:
            printf("Por favor ingrese una patente\n");
            scanf("%s",pat);
            control=0;
            while (!feof(a)){
                scanf(a,"%d %d %d %d %d %s %c",&cochera,&horaing,&mining,&horaegr,&minegr,patente,&turn);
                if (patente==pat){
                    printf(cochera,horaing,mining,horaegr,minegr,patente,turn);
                    control=1;
                }
            }
            if (control==0){
                printf("No se ha encontrado registro de esa patente.");
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            fclose(a);
        default:
            printf("Opcion invalida");
        break;
    }
    }
fclose(a);
}
```

> ```
> ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
> ||In function 'main':|
> |65|warning: passing argument 2 of 'sub_carga' from incompatible pointer type|
> |13|note: expected 'int * (*)[2]' but argument is of type 'int *'|
> |69|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast|
> |72|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast|
> |79|warning: passing argument 2 of 'sub_carga' from incompatible pointer type|
> |13|note: expected 'int * (*)[2]' but argument is of type 'int *'|
> |80|warning: passing argument 1 of 'sub_tiempoxcochera' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
> |35|note: expected 'int (*)[2]' but argument is of type 'int'|
> |83|warning: passing argument 2 of 'sub_carga' from incompatible pointer type|
> |13|note: expected 'int * (*)[2]' but argument is of type 'int *'|
> |84|warning: passing argument 2 of 'sub_tiempoxturno' from incompatible pointer type|
> |43|note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int *'|
> |87|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast|
> |90|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast|
> |100|warning: passing argument 1 of 'scanf' from incompatible pointer type|
> |347|note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'struct FILE *'|
> |102|warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
> |294|note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'|
> ||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 11 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
> ```

Comment: Hola @fran-marquinez, creo que si dieras un mejor formato a tu consulta, habría más personas dispuestas a ayudarte. Yo mismo iba a editarte el código para que fuera al menos legible.

Lo puedes pasar por un C formatter como [éste](http://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier) y utilizar las etiquetas que dispone Stackoverflow para el código.

Comment: Yo había intentado editarla y la han rechazado por apartarse de la intención original de la publicación ¿? y eso que no he cambiado ni un símbolo, sólo he marcado el código y puesto y quitado espacios... en fin

Comment: Si, tienes razon, intentare ser mas organizado

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje de error lo dice claro como el cristal (pero en Inglés). Permiteme traducirlo:

> ```
> warning: passing argument 2 of 'sub_carga' from incompatible pointer type|
> note: expected 'int * (*)[2]' but argument is of type 'int *'|
> ```

> ```
> alarma: pasando el argumento 2 de 'sub_carga' desde un tipo puntero incompatible|
> nota: se espera 'int * (*)[2]' pero el argumento es del tipo 'int *'|
> ```

Básicamente le pasas un puntero a entero y la función espera un puntero a arreglo de dos dimensiones de punteros a enteros. La firma de la función es esta:

```
void sub_carga (FILE *a, int*minxcochera[180][2])
```

Cuyo segundo parámetro recibe un arreglo a punteros a enteros (`int*[180][2]`). Sin embargo llamas a la función así:

```
sub_carga(a,&minxcoch[180][2]);
```

Cuando utilizas los corchetes sobre `minxcoch` estás accediendo a los datos, así que dado que `minxcoch` es un arreglo de 360 enteros, estás obteniendo un entero; acto seguido obtienes la dirección de dicho entero lo cual es, puntero a entero.

Cambia la firma de la función a:

```
void sub_carga (FILE *a, int minxcochera[180][2]) // Sin el puntero!
```

#### Información adicional.

Lo anterior responde a tu pregunta pero no resuelve tu problema, sospecho que querías pasar el arreglo `minxcoch` como puntero para modificarlo dentro de la función `sub_carga`.

Para que eso sea posible pasa la firma de la función a:

```
void sub_carga (FILE *a, int **minxcochera) // Puntero a puntero a int!
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!